# I have done a Video above as I am unable to move an image to the PSD in the correct size using the move tool. I am sure that there must be some method

Tags: adobe-photoshop

https://charitothemes.tinytake.com/sf/MjEzNTM1Ml82NjY4MzI4

I have done a Video above as I am unable to move an image to the PSD in the correct size using the move tool. I am sure that there must be some method.

Please let me Know if I have to improve my question in any way.

Comment: Please edit your post so the actual question is in the title. As the video shows, the moving works, but you expect it to be larger. It's a matter of resolution. The source you move is too small.

Comment: The size of image you are dragging is smaller in pixel dimensions than the image you are dropping it onto, hence the size difference.

Comment: I beg you Please do not downvote me. i want to delete thsi question. sorry i am just1 19 years old.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are even trying to do. Are you trying to use the image as a mockup of the computer screen as the current answer assumes? Your question makes no mention of that. Instead of deleting the question you should try and improve it so that we can at least understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: sir/Mam, I want to delete this question. I will not post unless I learn the rules here I already have lost the right to post a question. -4 downvotes → I am gone. Ican only request rest its upto you guys as you are senior.

Comment: You cannot delete your question if it has an upvoted answer and I am not going to delete the answer because you do not want to improve your question. If you can improve your question so it is clear and understandable and shows some effort then you have more chance of being upvoted and being able to post again.

Comment: Also note that deleting this question will *not* allow you to post again. Please see [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/307988)

Comment: My problem was solved by my school teacher so i do not need any help for now sir.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

You either adjust the image using distort or skew tool and scale it according to the screen size.

[image]

Or

Step 1: Select Lasso tool and create a shape according to the screen.

Step 2: Create a new layer and fill the selection with the desired color.

Step 3: Right click and Convert the layer into a smart object

Step 4: Double click on the smart object layer. A document will be opened

Step 5: Drag and drop the picture in the document and scale it with distort or skew tool to get the and save it.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69107/discussion-between-aiman-and-the-wp-novice).

Comment: Would it be possible sir if you can delete the answer as it is not going to serve any one in future.